# Returning only label columns & population from dbpedia query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to SPARQL and I'm a bit stuck on a part of an assignment I have. I'm querying dbpedia for all the countries in the European Union which have a total population >= 3000000. For each country I'd like to show their corresponding government type. I would like the final result set to contain 3 columns:

- the English label for each country
- the English label for each type of government
- the total population value

and then sorted descending on the total population.

```
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbrc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT DISTINCT ?country xsd:integer(?populationTotal) ?government_type ?engName ?gov_type

WHERE {
  ?country dct:subject dbrc:Member_states_of_the_European_Union ;
  a dbo:Country ; 
  rdfs:label ?engName .

  OPTIONAL { ?country dbo:governmentType ?government_type . ?government_type rdfs:label ?gov_type . }
  OPTIONAL { ?country dbo:populationTotal ?populationTotal . }

  FILTER (xsd:integer(?populationTotal) >= 3000000 && langMatches(lang(?engName), "en"))
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?gov_type), "en"))

} ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)
```

I've managed to get dbpedia to return all the info I need, however I'd like to only keep the columns above in bulletpoints and not the country column. I know there should be a way to return that country directly with the label however I'm having troubles getting any closer to a solution...

Comment: if you just want to have the 3 columns, why are not not just selecting those? I mean, you made the whole query and this is by far the most simple part, just enumerate the "columns" (in fact those are variables with its bindings) you're interested in. Or does this not work for you? I mean just doing `SELECT DISTINCT ?engName ?gov_type xsd:integer(?populationTotal)` looks pretty easy or not?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT (str(?countryLabel) as ?country) (str(?governmentTypeLabel) as ?government) (xsd:integer(?populationTotal) as ?population) WHERE {?c dct:subject dbrc:Member_states_of_the_European_Union ;
a dbo:Country ; rdfs:label ?countryLabel .OPTIONAL { ?c dbo:governmentType ?governmentType . ?governmentType rdfs:label ?governmentTypeLabel . FILTER (langMatches(lang(?governmentTypeLabel), "en"))} OPTIONAL { ?c dbo:populationTotal ?populationTotal . FILTER (xsd:integer(?populationTotal) >= 3000000)} FILTER(langMatches(lang(?countryLabel), "en"))} ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)`

Comment: By the way, as you can see, some countries have multiple values for government type.

Comment: so you have to use aggregation: (part1): `SELECT DISTINCT (str(?countryLabel) as ?country) (group_concat(str(?governmentTypeLabel); separator=", ") as ?governmentType) (xsd:integer(?populationTotal) as ?population)
WHERE {
  ?c dct:subject dbrc:Member_states_of_the_European_Union ;
  a dbo:Country ; 
  rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
`

Comment: (part2:): `OPTIONAL { ?c dbo:governmentType ?governmentType . ?governmentType rdfs:label ?governmentTypeLabel . FILTER (langMatches(lang(?governmentTypeLabel), "en"))}
  OPTIONAL { ?c dbo:populationTotal ?populationTotal . FILTER (xsd:integer(?populationTotal) >= 3000000)}
   FILTER(langMatches(lang(?countryLabel), "en"))
} 
GROUP BY ?c ?countryLabel ?populationTotal
ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)`

Comment: @AKSW, Thank you, indeed I got back to my pc and did that like 5 minutes after posting this and it worked, one of those situations...:D:D :)). Second part works like a charm as well, really handy. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: @NicoPana - You should post your solution, and accept your own answer. This site is not just about *your* solution, but the solution for people who run into the same question in the future...